# Neo4j Cypher: Find/Merge nodes having atleast 2 common nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to Graph DB and Neo4j and need help to query data which has atleast 2 common nodes

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q89S.png)

From the above graph, I need to get details of ROW1 and ROW2 as it 2 common nodes ID_B and ID_C

[Graph 2 with more nodes having common neighbor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQELF.png)

With Graph 2, I would need a merged details of Row1 , Row2 and Row3  as
Row1 & Row2 has ID_B, ID_C in common
Row2 & Row3 has ID_A ,ID_B C in common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would do it:

```
MATCH(r1:ROW)-[:HAS_ID]->(i)<-[:HAS_ID]-(r2:ROW)
WHERE id(r1) > id(r2)
WITH r1,r2, COLLECT(i) AS is
WHERE SIZE(is) > 1
RETURN r1,r2
```

In case you have multiple records and want your query to return the list of unique records that have two or more in common, you could do this:

```
MATCH(r1:ROW)-[:HAS_ID]->(i)<-[:HAS_ID]-(r2:ROW)
WHERE id(r1) > id(r2)
WITH [r1,r2] AS nodePair, COLLECT(i) AS is
WHERE SIZE(is) > 1
UNWIND nodePair AS node
RETURN DISTINCT node
```

Comment: This query also works fine for me. Can you let me know if I had to query for all nodes that have atleast 2 common neighbors and group them together. I have edited my original post with a graph with more nodes and what result I am looking for

Comment: expanded the answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
MATCH(r1:ROW)-[h1:HAS_ID]->(i1:ID)-[p1:PART_OF]->(r1)
MATCH(r2:ROW)-[h2:HAS_ID]->(i2:ID)-[p2:PART_OF]->(r2)
WHERE r1.ID <> r2.ID and i1.ID <> i2.ID
WITH r1, r2, COLLECT(i1) AS i1c, COLLECT(i2) AS i2c
WHERE SIZE(i1c) > 1 AND SIZE(i2c) > 1 AND SIZE(apoc.coll.intersection(i1c, i2c)) > 1
RETURN DISTINCT r1 AS row1, r2 AS row2, apoc.coll.intersection(i1c, i2c) AS ids
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. It works perfectly fine for 2 records. The graph I am working can have more nodes with common nodes (neighbors). I basically want to group all the nodes which has atleast 2 common node (neighbor).  Added a new graph to my original question with more nodes and relationship

Comment: @Graphileon 's second answer is the best.