# Neo4j Cypher: Find/Merge connected nodes with atleast 2 or more unique path

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Expanding my [pervious question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982200/neo4j-cypher-find-merge-nodes-having-atleast-2-common-nodes) in Neo4j how do I find nodes that are related/connect to other nodes with atleast 2/3 unique path.
For this [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d89O2.png)

for 2 unique path, I am looking for query with result

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| Row_1 | ROW_2, ROW_3,ROW_6 |

for 3 unique path

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| Row_2 | ROW_6 |

for 1 unique path

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| Row_1 | ROW_2,ROW_3,ROW_4, ROW_5,ROW_6 |

With this query,  I am getting 1-1 mapping between nodes but I am looking if I can get 1-n nodes in single query

```
MATCH(r1:Record)-[:HAS_ID]->(i)<-[:HAS_ID]-(r2:Record)
WHERE id(r1) > id(r2)
WITH r1,r2, COLLECT(i) AS is
WHERE SIZE(is) > 1 
RETURN r1.name, r2.name
```

Comment: You may want to accept the answer on your previous answer first .

Comment: Accepted. Thanks